# Find a string as value in a dictionary of dictionaries and return its key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-2.5

#### I need to write a function which is doing following work

Find a string as value in a dictionary of dictionaries and return its key
(1st key if found in main dictionary, 2nd key if found in sub dictionary).

#### Source Code

Here is the function which I try to implement, but it works incorrect as **I can't find any answer of how to convert list into dictionary** as in this case the following error occurs

> for v, k in l:
> ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

```
def GetKeyFromDictByValue(self, dictionary, value_to_find):
    """"""

    key_list = [k for (k, v) in dictionary.items() if v == value_to_find]
    if key_list.__len__() is not 0:
        return key_list[0]
    else:
        l = [s for s in dictionary.values() if  ":" in str(s)]
        d = defaultdict(list)
        for v, k in l:
            d[k].append(v)

        print d

dict = {'a': {'a1': 'a2'}, "aa": "aa1", 'aaa': {'aaa1': 'aaa2'}}
print GetKeyFromDictByValue(dict, "a2")
```

**I must do this on Python 2.5**

Comment: Use `len(key_list)`, *not* `key_list.__len__()`. And non-zero values are boolean true:  `if len(key_list):` suffices.

Comment: You should not name your variable `dict`; that masks the built-in type and actually prevents you from using `isinstance()` on values here as you now cannot test for that type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You created a list of *only* the dictionary values, but then try to loop over it as if it already contains both keys and values of those dictionaries. Perhaps you wanted to loop over each matched dictionary?

```
l = [v for v in dictionary.values() if  ":" in str(v)]
d = defaultdict(list)
for subdict in l:
    for k, v in subdict.items():
```

I'd instead *flatten* the structure:

```
def flatten(dictionary):
    for key, value in dictionary.iteritems():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            # recurse
            for res in flatten(value):
                yield res
        else:
            yield key, value
```

then just search:

```
def GetKeyFromDictByValue(self, dictionary, value_to_find):
    for key, value in flatten(dictionary):
        if value == value_to_find:
            return key
```

Demo:

```
>>> sample = {'a': {'a1': 'a2'}, "aa": "aa1", 'aaa': {'aaa1': 'aaa2'}}
>>> GetKeyFromDictByValue(None, sample, "a2")
'a1'
```